# Creating specific options in `Manipulate[]`

Tags: manipulate

Suppose I want to manipulate the plot of $A\sin(\omega t)$ with specific combinations of 3-parameter values, say $A$, $\omega$ and `PlotStyle[]`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Sin[\[Omega] t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> pStyle], {{A, \[Omega], 
   pStyle}, {{1, 10, Black}, {2, 15, Red}, {3, 5, Blue}}}]
```

The objective is to keep only 3 choices of options (either 3 buttons or a drop down list with these specific combinations) open to the user instead of the regular 27 choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Manipulate` can't handle multiple variables for a single control, as you've probably noticed. One simple approach is to introduce a helper variable (`setting` in the code below) that can be set to the triples of values, which are then distributed onto the individual variables:

```
Manipulate[
 {A, ω, pStyle} = setting;
 Plot[A Sin[ω t], {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> pStyle],
 {setting, {{1, 10, Black}, {2, 15, Red}, {3, 5, Blue}}}
 ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can create the `SetterBar` manually (similar to @SjoerdSmit's answer), since that supports "composite" variable specifications:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Sin[ω t], {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> pStyle],
 {
  setting, 
  SetterBar[
    Dynamic[{A, ω, pStyle}], {{1, 10, Black}, {2, 15, Red}, {3,
       5, Blue}}] &
  }
 ]
```

Note that I'm cheating a bit by giving the variable specification `{setting, func&}` to `Manipulate`, where `func` simply returns the `SetterBar` control. This is an easy way to specify a fully custom control with a label, but it might be considered a bit ugly (since `setting` is not actually used)

Answer (score 7):

```
Manipulate[Plot[# Sin[#2 t], {t, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> #3] & @@ setter,
 {{setter, {1, 10, Black}, Row[{"{A", "ω", "pStyle}"}, ","]},
  {{1, 10, Black}, {2, 15, Red}, {3, 5, Blue}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you were trying to do is actually possible if you define your own `PopupMenu` control:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Sin[\[Omega] t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> pStyle],
 Grid[
  {{"A",
    PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[{A, \[Omega], pStyle}],
      # -> First[#] & /@ {{1, 10, Black}, {2, 15, Red}, {3, 5, Blue}}
    ]
    }}
 ]
]
```

In this example I decided to label the items in the menu with the values for `A`, but you can define other labels if you want. Note, however, that this doesn't localize the control variables. If you want that, use a `DynamicModule` around the `Manipulate` (which you can also use to initialize the values for the variables).